# How to end-to-end test my React.js code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium, testing, end-to-end

I try to use Selenium webdriver.io for E2E testing but implementation was relatively hard.

Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the problem statement? What exactly you are trying to test. Is it the react components or you are trying to test the application from end user perspective?

Comment: Sure, I am trying to test my Portal E2E like the user does, enter a username, password press login etc.Are there any alternative tools that can do this kind of tests?